# WordPress add inline styles, how to add background-size property

Tags: wordpress

Adding dynamic styles that load custom options in Theme options area but I am stumped on how to add background-size property.  Each time I add it I get "invalid property value."  Here is what I am using;

```
$style_setting = $cust['title_size'];
$style_line = ".title-image { background-size: {$style_setting}; }";
wp_add_inline_style( 'main_css', $style_line);
```

I was able to get background images to load using {background: url({$style_setting}); but I'm not sure how to get image properties added to inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks valid

if you would like to load any image and set background size you can do it this way

```
$style_setting = 'contain'; //example setting
$style_line = "body { background-size: {$style_setting}; background-image:url('https://example.com/image.jpg'); }";
```

Please just remember that you should use valid properties for `background-size` which are following:

- Using the keyword values contain or cover.
- Using a width value only, in which case the height defaults to auto.
- Using both a width and a height value, in which case the first sets the width and the second sets the height. Each value can be a , a , or auto.

as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but when I place the code for background-size:{$style_setting}; it comes back in the front end on the browser as invalid property value.  Background image works with $style_line = ".title-image {background:url ( {$style_settings};) }; but all attempts to add size, repeat, and other values come across in browser as invalid

Comment: Please show me the code you use. What kind of options you use for background-size? Are you sure you are using only valid values like "contain' or "cover" ?